# Vora 1.3 Thriftserver cannot start

Tags: vora

I'm deploying Vora 1.3 Services on HDP 2.3 using the Manager web UI. Mostly default configuration and nodes assignment. I've assigned Vora Thriftserver service to the node that's been successfully hosting the same service of Vora 1.2 (which I removed already).

The service doesn't start though. Here's the related part of the log:

```
17/01/23 10:04:27 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
17/01/23 10:04:27 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
17/01/23 10:04:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/01/23 10:04:27 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://<jumpbox>:4040
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.3/services/vora-manager/package/lib/vora-spark/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.3.102-assembly.jar at http://<jumpbox>:41874/jars/spark-sap-datasources-1.3.102-assembly.jar with timestamp 1485126268263
17/01/23 10:04:28 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 37523.
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 37523
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:37523 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 37523)
17/01/23 10:04:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkPlanner
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.sap.thriftserver.SapSQLEnv$.init(SapSQLEnv.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SapThriftServer$.main(SapThriftServer.scala:22)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SapThriftServer.main(SapThriftServer.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
(.... goes on...)
```

Spark executable and Java executable paths in the Vora Thriftserver configuration tab are correct.

Did I miss something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running Vora 1.3 which means you must use HDP 2.4.2 which includes the required Spark 1.6.1 version. See the official Vora [product availability matrix (PAM)](https://support.sap.com/content/dam/library/ssp/infopages/pam-essentials/HANAVoraPAM.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri! Is there any coordination of Hadoop version requirements for Vora an NLS at SAP internally? I mean, if I want to upgrade my HDP to fit Vora, would I be able to use the same installation for NLS -- prerequisite versions in the Note 2363218 look _very_ old.